# Debugger displaying HTML instead of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, owncloud

I am passing an html template of the previewer of Impressionist App for ownCloud, I am working on in js/templ.js and obviously impress.js will be called in the template via it. The src is correct, but then also my chrome debugger displays html as content in my impress.js file and console also gives javascript syntax error, due to the html being called. Why does it happen? Any clue?
The source code of my app can be found [here](https://github.com/owncloud/apps/tree/master/impressionist). 
Also, I am attaching an image of what I see in the debugger[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nkhv.png)

Comment: If you are using ownCloud, try creating and previewing a Presentation  on Impressionist. A new window should pop up, check the debugger there. :)

Comment: *The src is correct I suppose* :you suppose or are you sure? Maybe what you see there is the result of a wrong scripts-src and an ErrorDocument-directive

Comment: I am sure :) edited the question